# MATLAB Indexing - Changing only nonzero elements from specific columns

Tags: matlab, indexing

How do I change only the nonzero values of the first 5 columns of a 10x10 array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first alternative is to select the columns you want to change and use binary indexing:

```
A = round(rand(10, 10));
B = A(:, 1:5);
B(B ~= 0) = 10;
A(:, 1:5) = B
```

A second alternative is to use a mask as follows:

```
A = round(rand(10, 10));
mask = zeros(size(A));
mask(:, 1:5) = 1;
A(A~=0 & mask) = 10
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to change the first 5 columns only and also not the zero elements but the nonzero ones.

Comment: I missed that first, but I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you already accept the right answer, so I'll add just for the documentation, a solution with one line and one variable, if someone will find it more comfortable:

```
A((A(:,1:5))~=0)=10
```

EDIT:

For @m7913d comment, more general solution for columns n1 to n2, can be-

```
A((n1-1)*size(A,1)+find(A(:,n1:n2)~=0))=10
```

Comment: Nice one line solution. Note that this solution only works for the first n rows. The result will not be correct for the slightly different question where you want to change columns n1 to n2.

Comment: @m7913d You absolutely right. I edited my answer to more general case